# Apache2 on Mac OSX: How to Get Shared Object Libs such as mod_authn_alias.so

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, shared-libraries

I am trying to start apache2, but I am missing some modules required by the config.

```
$ apachectl -k start
httpd: Syntax error on line 64 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: 
    Cannot load /etc/apache2/modules/mod_authn_alias.so into server:
    dlopen(/etc/apache2/modules/mod_authn_alias.so, 10): image not found
```

How to I get this file and the other missing *.so files, if any?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably using a 2.2 configuration file on a 2.4 server. This module doesn't exist in 2.4, its functionality was moved into mod_authn_core.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html